# Is there a way to show Intellisense autocomplete of classes that are imported to .js

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio-code, mjs

I have 2 files, module.mjs and project.js. In module.mjs there are all functions and classes used in project.js file.

My problem is that I can't see class methods or suggestions or even class suggestions in project.js file, that are imported from module file. It would't be a problem, that it doesn't suggest, If I only had few class methods, but I don't.

I am using this import sentence:

```
import * as func from './modules/functions.mjs'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing .mjs to .js helped me, now everything in Intellisense autocomplete is showing as it should.